# Как сохранить переменную js

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Как сохранить переменную, находящуюся в скрипте javascript для дальнейшего использования её в дальнейшем в asp.net mvc?

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
    chart_div.innerHTML = '<img src="' + chart.getImageURI() + '">';
    console.log(chart_div.innerHTML);
    });

chart.draw(data, options);
var img = chart.getImageURI();
document.getElementById('image').src = img;
```

Как сохранить переменную chart.grtImageURI() ?

Answer (score 1):

Если это всё происходит на одной и той же странице и переменная о которой вы говорите приватная, то можно объявить её глобальной и пользоваться во всех других функциях. Например так:

```
window['chartimg'] = chart.grtImageURI();
```

в этом случае chartimg будет доступна всем.

```
console.log(typeof chartimg != 'undefined' ? chartimg : 'sorry no image exist');
```